# Отправка файла с Android на FTP сервер

Tags: java, android, ftp

Одна из задач моего учебного проекта - передать файл с Android-смартфона на FTP сервер.
Погуглив, нашел, что это можно сделать с помощью библиотеки Apache Commons.
Библиотеку успешно подключил в проект, добавил в AndroidManifest.xml разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Далее, воспользовался примером загрузки файла на FTP сервер:

```
public static void ftpConn(String hostAddress, String log, String password) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FTPClient fClient = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream fInput = new FileInputStream("Android/data/название_пакета/Yes.txt");
    String fs = "Yes.txt";
    try {
        fClient.connect(hostAddress);
        fClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        fClient.login(log, password);
        fClient.storeFile(fs, fInput);
        fClient.logout();
        fClient.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Обработчик события на кнопку, по нажатию на которую будет производиться отправка файла:

```
try {
    ftpConn("n***.n****.ru","*****","*****");
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Неудача", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Файл, который необходимо отправить я поместил во внутреннюю память устройства: Android/data/название_пакета/Yes.txt. Пробовал прописывать различные пути файла в строку:

```
FileInputStream fInput = new FileInputStream("Android/data/название_пакета/Yes.txt");
```

Но ничего не получалось. Приложение ловило исключение и выводило Toast: "Неудача".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Я думаю, что ошибка в том, что я неверно указываю путь к файлу.

PS: Программу запускал на Nexus 5 с Android 6.

PSS: Данный пример отправки файла на FTP пытался запустить на компьютере - все получилось с первого раза.

Comment: Покажите стек-трейс.

Comment: Думаю проблемы у вас даже две: путь действительно указываете неверный, надо указывать полный, что то типа `"/mnt/sdcard0/Android/data/название_пакета/Yes.txt"`; ну и когда найдете верный путь к файлу вашем приложению скорее всего понадобятся права на чтение внешних файлов [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), а начиная с андройд 6 эти права надо не только прописать в манифесте, но и проверять и при необходимости запрашивать перед чтением файла.

Answer (score 2):

В `FileInputStream` должен быть передан либо относительный путь к файлу (от корня файловой системы вашего проекта), либо абсолютный. Абсолютный начинается со слеша `/` и указывает полный путь к файлу от корня файловой системы устройства.

У вас сейчас путь относительный (без слеша в начале) но явно не корректный.

Насколько я понимаю, приложению недоступны другие расположения по внутренней памяти, кроме директории самого приложения. Поэтому, файл должен лежать в проекте.

Получить абсолютный путь к файлу можно примерно таким образом:

```
String yourFilePath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "hello.txt";
```

и использовать его следующим образом:

```
FileInputStream fInput = new FileInputStream(yourFilePath);
```

У меня на тестовом проекте вызов `getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()` вернул

> /data/user/0/com.example.note.test/files

Comment: А не подскажете, как приложению получить доступ к другим расположениям по внутренней памяти? Случайно, не разрешением в манифесте: " <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> "?

Comment: @AndreiO. Посмотрите вот здесь: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html Ваше приложение не сможет получить права на чтение любых файлов во внутренней памяти. Это же безумие - все системные файлы и файлы других приложений... Вам доступны внешнее хранилище и отведенный вам "кусочек" внутреннего (ну и файлы других прилов во внутренней, которые владельцы специально пометили доступными для других). Для остального нужен root-доступ.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `Context.getFilesDir()`, чтобы получить путь к внутренней памяти устройства

Например:

```
FileInputStream fInput = new FileInputStream(getFilesDir() + "/Android/data/название_пакета/Yes.txt");
```